# Android SDK Can't Find android.bat?

Tags: android-sdk

I just downloaded the Android SDK (primarily for the purpose of running SDK Manager to install the Google USB drivers to connect a device), but the SDK Manager fails to run.  I get the following error:

[image]

I can confirm, however, that there is an `android.bat` in the `tools` folder, which is one folder above the SDK Manager executable.

Has anybody run into this before?

For reference I'm on Windows 7 64 bit and I downloaded the 64 bit ADT Bundle to try to run this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it: we need to copy those `SDK Manager.exe` and `AVD Manager.exe` to the SDK root folder, I needed to copy them to `C:\android-sdk\`, this is because, `SDK Manager.exe` and `AVD Manager.exe` are looking for tools.

Answer (score 2):

It's because it's looking for a relative path from the .../sdk/tools/lib/ folder, as that is where you are running the exe from.

I have not run Windows in a while, so bear with me, but if you open a command line, navigate to the .../sdk folder, then run the SDK manager from there by typing

```
tools/lib/SDK Manager.exe
```

I suspect it will work.

For easier access, you can create a shortcut to the SDK manager on the desktop, open the properties of the shortcut and change the 'Start Directory' (?) to the base .../sdk folder. Let me know if this does not work.

Comment: You know, I like this answer a lot more than the anonymous user's answer, but Windows had other plans.  (I'm also not well versed in Windows command-line usage, what there is of it.)  When executed from the command line in the desired start path, the application doesn't even come up.  Same with the shortcut trick.  No message as to why, it just exits without error before presenting anything to the UI.  But the other guy's solution, which I'm not comfortable with as a long-term fix, got it running for me.  Since I only need it once to install some stuff, I have to go with it.  Thanks!

Comment: Fair enough - like I said, I haven't used Windows in a while and I don't have one to try this with :) It *should* work, but there may be other reasons why it doesn't.